# Why is $\wedge ^2 E[p] \cong \mu_p$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, formal-power-series, torsion-groups

As the title says,  why is $$\wedge ^2 E[p] \cong \mu_p,$$ where $E[p]$ refers to the $p$-torsion points of an Elliptic curve over a number field $K$, $\wedge$ refers to the exterior product and $\mu_p$ refers to the group of $p^{th}$ roots of unity.

I know that for the formal multiplicative group $\mathbb{G}_m$ over $K$, $\operatorname{Tor}\mathbb{G}_m(K)$ contains all the roots of unity in $K$. I know you can also define formal group laws on elliptic curves. Was wondering if that is the direction to go?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weil_pairing looks related

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $k$ be of characteristic coprime to $p$ and $E/k$.

The first thing to note is that $E[p]$ is an $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector space of rank $2$. The exterior square of $E[p]$ is therefore an $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector space of rank $1$ (spanned by the wedge of the independent basis vectors). Indeed, this is the case for any $k$-vector space of dimension $2$.

The non-trivial thing here is that the Galois action is really making $\bigwedge^2 E[p] \cong \mu_p$ *as group schemes* (or if you prefer as $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector spaces with a $\operatorname{Gal}(\bar k/k)$ action).

Recall that elements of $\bigwedge^2 V$ correspond to alternating bilinear forms on $V$ (were $V/K$ is a $K$-vector space). It comes equipped with a natural Galois action.

The Weil pairing is an alternating, symmetric, bi-linear, non-degenerate form $e_p : E[p] \times E[p] \to \mu_p$ *and* it is Galois equivariant. You can see this because the Weil pairing is a *non-trivial* alternating Galois equivariant bilinear form, and it therefore spans $\bigwedge^2 E[p]$ (it is a non-trivial element of a rank $1$ vector space). The Galois action follows by construction.

Comment: Mummy's answer is spot-on. I just thought I would mention that this is really a speical case of the Poincare pairing on etale (co)homology. Namely, identifying $H_1(E,\mathbb{Z}/p)$ with $E[p]$ one can identify the Weil pairing on $E[p]$ with the Poincare pairing $H_1(E,\mathbb{Z}/p)\times H_1(E,\mathbb{Z}/p)\to \mu_p$ on etale homology. So, this is really not special to elliptic curves, and is a more general algebro-geometric phenomenon (e.g. that changes little if you replace $E$ by a more general curve).

Comment: Hi @alex, beautiful comment! Maybe this warrants its own question, I guess what you're saying is that the Weil pairing is a cleverly realised intersection pairing on étale homology. In general I can then think of the Weil pairing as an intersection on 1st and $(d-1)$-th étale homology ($(d-1)$-th being canonically identified with the 1st on the dual?). Is there some very nice way then of viewing (say) middle étale homology on abelian varieties? (I guess I want to have $\mathbb{Z}/p$ coefficients everywhere)